# Python Glueviz - is there a way to replace ie update the imported data

Tags: python

I am using Glueviz 0.7.2 as part of the Anaconda package, on OSX. Glueviz is a data visualization and exploration tool.

I am regularly regenerating an updated version of the same data set from an external model, then importing that data set into Glueviz.

Currently I can not find a way to have Glueviz refresh or update an existing imported data set.

I can add a new data set, ie a second more updated version of the data from the model as a new import data set, but this does not replace the original, and does not enable the new data to show in the graphs set up in Glueviz in a simple way.

It seems the only solution to plot the updated data, is to start a new session, and needing to take some time to set up all the plots again. Most tedious!

As a python running application, Glueviz must  be storing the imported data set somewhere. Hence I thinking a work around would be to replace that existing data with the updated data. With a restart of Glueviz, and a reload of that saved session, I imagine it will not know the difference and simply graph the updated data set within the existing graphs. Problem solved.

I am not sure how Glueviz as a python package stores the data file, and what python application would be the best to use to update that data file.

Comment: Opening a Glueviz session file in BBEdit, it appears this file does not have the imported data stored in it, as I had assumed. This seems to be a .jsonfile. The only reference I can find to the imported data, is a glue.core.data_factories.helpers.LoadLog, and a path to the original excel file holding the data. Perhaps this is reloaded each time from the source file. This does seem to suggest if I update this source file, this may be the solution. About to do a check and if correct will post as an answer.

Comment: The danger of unconscious assumptions. It turns out the solution is that simple, replace/update the source data file.  For some reason I assumed that the data was imported from the source file, and stored within the session file saved by Glueviz. Hence access via terminal and python to affect an update. To think I have struggled with this issue for 3 months or more. (Slap forehead.) Another case of miss the most obvious!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the data is not stored in the Glueviz session file, but rather loaded fresh each time the saved session is opened from the original data source file.

Hence the solution is simple:  Replace the data source file with a new file (of the same type) in with the updated data.

The updated data file must have the exact same name, be in the exact same location, and I assume, must have only values within the source data file changed, not the amount of data or columns titles or other aspects changed from the original file.

Having done that, reopen Glueviz, reload that session file, and the graphs in Glueviz should update with the updated data.